# Is the following if statement unnecessary?

Tags: c#

I have a small piece of code that checks some data but I suspect one of the if statements is unnecessary:

```
bool meldControleGereed = false;
bool allProductionDone = true;
int controleBewerkingId = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in controleTable.Rows)
{
    string code = row.Field<string>("CODE");
    bool productionDone = row.Field<int>("PRODUCTIONDONE") == 1;

    if (allProductionDone && (code == "1885" || code == "1887")) //controle niveau 1 en niveau 3
    {
        if(productionDone && (code == "1885" || code == "1887"))
        {
            cacheItem.ProductionDoneCheck = 0;
            cacheItem.ProductionDone = controleBewerkingId;
        }
        else
        {
            meldControleGereed = true;
            controleBewerkingId = row.Field<int>("PK_R_JOBORDERDETAILWORKACTIVITY");
        }                        
    }
    else
    {
        if (!productionDone)
            allProductionDone = false;
    }
}
```

I'm obviously talking about `if(productionDone) && (code == "" || code =="")`.

Comment: You're not telling us enough about the logic of the code. For instance: `bool allProductionDone = true;` -- should that by default be true?

Comment: @BCdotWEB it can be in this situation. `allProductionDone` *can* change in the `foreach` loop and it's also used in the loop in a condition.

Comment: @Abbas Sure, it *can* be, but *should* it be? Especially considering the main question of @CKY is whether this first `if` is superfluous. Hence my request for more background, because right now this code feels "buggy".

Comment: The desire to improve code is implied for all questions on this site. Question titles should reflect the purpose of the code, not how you wish to have it reworked. See [ask].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First a few small points:

**The `var` keyword:**

From the [**C# Programming Guide**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx):

> The var keyword can also be useful when the specific type of the variable is tedious to type on the keyboard, or is obvious, or does not add to the readability of the code.

So lines like:

```
bool meldControleGereed = false;
```

would become:

```
var meldControleGereed = false;
```

---

**Curly braces:**

Even if you only have one line of code in an `if`, `foreach`, `...` statement, it's best practice to keep the curly braces. It improves readability of your code and the code is less error prone.

```
if (!productionDone)
    allProductionDone = false;
```

becomes:

```
if (!productionDone)
{
    allProductionDone = false;
}
```

---

Now, to the question. In your code the second check for the `code` variable to be equal to `1885` or `1887` is redundant. If you get to following line:

```
if(productionDone && (code == "1885" || code == "1887"))
```

That means two things:

- `allProductionDone` is `true`
- `code` is equal to either `1885` or `1887`

Since you won't do anything further with those variables, the second if-statement should just read as:

```
if(productionDone)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily agree with the `var` bit. One of the nice things about C# is that with it being strongly typed, often times if you know what type you are looking for it makes it easier to find. (It's easy to look at the beginning of the line for variables that match `bool *` rather than `var * = false` et al. At least without using `var` you can immediately tell what type it is.)

Comment: @EBrown I can follow your reasoning, I was just trying to show him the conventions provided by Microsoft itself. Although the usage is personal of course! ;)

Comment: @EBrown, if you have so many variables that you need to scan them by type, then using types rather than var is masking the real problem: you have too many variables. Good rule of thumb: no method longer than 30 lines; no class longer than 300. From experience, everyone who sticks to those principles also uses var in preference to explicitly specifying the type.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good idea to move hardcoded "magic" strings to constant fields with descriptive names. It will help you avoid silly mistakes, such as accidently typing "1886" instead of "1887". You will also be able to easily change string value without the need to go through you code looking for places where you used value "1887".

Comment: Alternatively, he could extract a method like `bool IsAControlCode(string code) { return code == "1885" || code == "1887"; }` - the idea being that magic numbers never get repeated; but they don't necessarily need to be constants.

Comment: @ANeves, yep, thats another valid option.